# combine two dataframe with duplicated columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes, A and B.
I want to combine them by `pandas.concat([A, B], axis = 1)`.
However, there are some duplicated columns in it as below:

```
# A
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 TL

# B
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
```

The value under `Col1-Col5` in data `B` are different with the one in data `A`.
How to get a new dataframe with column, `ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 TL`.
`ID` and `TL` is from data `A` but `Col1-Col5` are from data `B`.

Comment: Do these DataFrames have some index that ensures alignment between them?

Comment: The order has already fixed. Just combine.

Comment: Providing example DataFrames makes it easier for ppl to answer. [mcve]

Comment: `da[['c1','c2']] = db[['c1','c2']]`?

Comment: `pd.concat([da['ID'],db[['c1','c2']], da['TL']], 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @wwii setup.
Let use `combine_first`:

```
db.combine_first(da)
```

Output:

```
  ID TL  c1  c2
0  a  q  10  20
1  b  r  11  21
2  c  s  12  22
3  d  t  13  23
4  e  u  14  24
```

Comment: @PeterChan  Did this solution help you?  Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) a solution?

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks! It works and it should be a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
da = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abcde'), 'c1':range(5),'c2':range(5), 'TL':list('qrstu')})
db = pd.DataFrame({'c1':range(10,15),'c2':range(20,25)})
```

Not clear what you need, here are a few.

```
da.update(db)

da[['c1','c2']] = db[['c1','c2']]

cols = [c for c in da.columns if c in db.columns]
da[cols] = db[cols]

dc = pd.concat([da['ID'],db[['c1','c2']], da['TL']], 1)
```